# How to create an if else statement when using custom calculatoin script

Tags: javascript, kofax

I am new to using Kofax Power Editor, which uses Javascript, and I am trying to create an if else statement that involves simple calculations. It depends on what the user enters into a textfield box, and then displays it in a separate text field box. Here is the line I wrote:

```
if (Textfield1 <= 15,000) { Textfield3 = (Textfield1*.05)/12; }
```

Although, nothing is showing up in Textfield3. I have no clue why.

If anyone would like to help, I am available via phone as well. Or facetime.... because this not making any sense to me.

Comment: lose the comma in 15,000

Comment: You can't have commas in numbers; use `15000` instead. In that context, the comma leads to this being evaluated as `if (000)` which is always false.

Comment: may be use `if (Number(Textfield1.value) <= 15000) ...`

Comment: What if you do something very simple like `Textfield3 = 123;`, does that work for you? With JavaScript you usually set a textfield's `.value` but I've never used that editor.

Comment: That didn't work either Chris G. Then there must be something wrong with Textfield3 then.

Comment: Can someone just call me.... or like Facetime.... because they really got me doing this as an intern and I never said I knew how to code to them..... Plus I aint never heard of Kofax before and I doubt any of yall have either.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma `,` which is interpreted as [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and all checks yields `false`, because of zero value.

To overcome this, remove the comma.

```js
var Textfield1 = 42,
    Textfield3;

if (Textfield1 <= 15000) { Textfield3 = (Textfield1*.05)/12; }

console.log(Textfield3); // undefined
```

Comment: That makes sense. I removed the comma and still nothing shows up in Textfield3. Am I missing an output line or something.

Comment: it depends on your library.